# How can i export environments into a PHP file from gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: php, environment-variables, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I set the environment variables in gitlab and i want to export these into a PHP file.

I want to do it for using passwords in acceptance tests and i dont want that these passwords are readable in the files.

This is my gitlab-ci.yml, the last line is my try to export the Variable.

```
before_script:
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
  - echo "$DEPLOY_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
  - echo "$FE_PASS" > "$(pwd)/deploy/dev/codeception/tests/acceptance/ExtranetCept.php"
```

Comment: Your code seems correct, what is the problem?

Comment: @Jerodev My acceptance test passed but he doesn´t started the test and the Password is readable in the command line

Comment: @Jerodev he dont export the password into the php file